# Responsive Menu Using Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

[image: Menu]

Can Any one help me for the menu creating using Bootstrap CSS
every tutorial of bootstrap menu does not full fill my requirement
so please can any one tell me how to create Responsive menu

Image contains two images 1 for normal browser and another image is for mobile

I have tried the following code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Example of Twitter Bootstrap 3 Static Navbar Extended</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.3/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
     <style type="text/css">
         .bs-example{
        margin: 20px;
            }
     </style>
<script>

</script>
</head> 
<body>
<div class="bs-example">
    <nav role="navigation" class="navbar navbar-default">
        <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" data-target="#navbarCollapse" data-toggle="collapse" class="navbar-toggle">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
           <!--  <a href="#" class="navbar-brand">Brand</a> -->
        </div>
        <!-- Collection of nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
        <div id="navbarCollapse" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a>                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Profile</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Login</a></li>
              </ul>
            <!-- <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li><a href="#">Login</a></li>
            </ul> -->
        </div>
    </nav>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Its always a good idea to post some code with what you have tried so far to show people that you actually made an effort to solve the problem yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got my solution :
following is the code i required:

```
                    <!DOCTYPE html>
                    <html lang="en">
                    <head>
                    <meta charset="UTF-8">
                    <title>Example of Twitter Bootstrap 3 Static Navbar Extended</title>
                    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
                    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.3/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
                    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
                    <script src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
                    <style type="text/css">
                        .bs-example{
                            margin: 20px;
                        }
                    </style>
                    <script>
                      $(document).ready(function(){

                                $(window).resize(function(){

                                    console.log($(window).width());
                                    if($(window).width()<767)
                                    {
                                        $(".navbar-brand").html($(".active>a").text());
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        $(".navbar-brand").html("");
                                    }

                                });

                                $("ul>li").click(function(){

                                        //alert($(this).find("a").text());
                                        $(".active").removeClass("active");
                                        $(this).addClass("active");
                                        if($("#navbarCollapse").hasClass("in"))
                                        {
                                            $("#navbarCollapse").removeClass("in")
                                            $("#navbarCollapse").addClass("collapse")
                                        }

                                        if($(window).width()<767)
                                        {
                                            $(".navbar-brand").html($(".active>a").text());
                                        }
                                        else
                                        {
                                            $(".navbar-brand").html("");
                                        }


                                });
                      });
                    </script>
                    </head> 
                    <body>
                    <div class="bs-example">
                        <nav role="navigation" class="navbar navbar-default">
                            <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
                            <div class="navbar-header">
                                <button type="button" data-target="#navbarCollapse" data-toggle="collapse" class="navbar-toggle">
                                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                                </button>
                                <a href="#" class="navbar-brand"></a>  
                            </div>
                            <!-- Collection of nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
                            <div id="navbarCollapse" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
                                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                                    <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Profile</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Login</a></li>
                                  </ul>
                            </div>
                        </nav>
                    </div>
                    </body>
                    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked these examples?

- [Bootstrap navbar](http://getbootstrap.com/examples/navbar/)
- [Bootstrap navbar-static-top/](http://getbootstrap.com/examples/navbar-static-top/)
- [Bootstrap navbar-fixed-top/](http://getbootstrap.com/examples/navbar-fixed-top/)

do exactly what you need

in addition, [this](http://twbscolor.smarchal.com/) utility allows you to create the bootstrap navbar

### UPDATE

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/qC2PM/)

```
<div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation" id="test">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#link1" style="display:none;" id="link">item 1</a>
    </div>
    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#link1">item 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#link2">item 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#link2">item 3</a></li>

      </ul>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>


$(document).ready(function() {

//control for the creation
if($(window).width() < 767){
       $("#link").show();
    }

});

$(document).load($(window).bind("resize", do_menu));

function do_menu(){

   if($(window).width() < 767){
      $("#link").show();
   }else{
       $("#link").hide();
   }

}
```

Comment: Yes in all this examples when i go for mobile it shows Brand name at TOP i want active link instead of Project Name means link which is clicked     Thanks for the link but in that link i cant change the functionality

Comment: instead of the name of the menu you would like to see the first item in the menu?

Comment: Yes ,   And the item which i will click

Comment: Now I create a jsfiddle and then updates the answer :)

Comment: NO Nicolo its not the case you only changed the navbar-brand  but i want when i click the particular item that should come at the menu name and menu should get closed

Answer (score 0):

I've modified the twitter bootstrap HTML code, i believe the below solution is pretty much close what you expect

```
<!-- Static navbar -->
      <div class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
        <div class="container-fluid">
          <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
              <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand hidden-lg" href="#" data-toggle="dropdown">Project name</a>
          </div>
          <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
              <li class="active"><a href="#">1 First Topic</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">1 First Topic</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">1 First Topic</a></li>

            </ul>

          </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
        </div><!--/.container-fluid -->
      </div>
```